# How to select an image from gallery when clicking a button (Xamarin iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiimagepickercontroller

I've taken a look at this code snippet: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/choose_a_photo_from_the_gallery/ unfortunately this loads the gallery immediately and doesn't take into consideration giving the user an option to select first.

I'm trying to give the user two options:

1 - take a photo
2 - choose an existing photo from gallery

Both of these would be buttons you click on. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to display an ActionSheet with `Prism.IPageDialogService` to give choices to the user. You can even do something like this to have a cross-platform solution:

```
private async void AddImage() // This is your method for your button
{
    string chosen = await _dialogService.DisplayActionSheetAsync("Which source do you want to use?", "Cancel", null, "Camera", "Galery");
    if (chosen == "Camera")
    {
        TakePhoto();
    }
    else if (chosen == "Galery")
    {
        PickPhoto();
    }
}
```

Implementation of `TakePhoto()`:

```
private async void TakePhoto()
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        await _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Warning", "Camera not available", "OK");
        return;
    }

    _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        SaveToAlbum = true,
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "sample" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg"
    });

    if (_mediaFile == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ImageButtonAddGroup = _mediaFile.Path;
}
```

Implementation of `PickPhoto()`:

```
private async void PickPhoto()
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
        await _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Warning", "Camera not available", "OK");
        return;
    }

    _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
    if (_mediaFile == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    ImageButtonAddGroup = _mediaFile.Path;
}
```

If you want two buttons instead of one, you don't need the `Prism.IPageDialogService` and you can just bind the methods `TakePhoto()` and `PickPhoto()` to two different buttons.